# Length of longest path in Erdos Renyi graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Is it possible to compute the expected length of the longest simple path in an Erdos-Renyi graph or even the probability density function of this length?

Comment: If you are talking about graphs where for every edge you take it with some probability $p$, then this depends on $p$. For very small $p$ the graph does not matter, on the other hand, for greater than $\frac{c\log n}{n}$ the probability that the graph contains a Hamilton cycle tends to 1 (for some big constant $c$ and $n \to \infty$). Anything in-between seems like a hard problem.

Comment: @dtldarek I am exactly talking about that situation. Does your observation hold even for directed graphs?

Comment: My info comes from [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.91.714), and the result is for undirected graphs. As for directed graphs, I have no idea. Have you tried googling for the results? My searches return titles that seem relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may be hard to get an exact distribution, there are results giving asymptotic information on the length of the longest path.

- If $p=\frac{c}{n}$ where $c<1$, then the largest component in the graph with high probability has size $O(\log n)$, so there almost surely won't be a path longer than this.
- If $p=\frac{c}{n}$, where $c>1$ is constant, then there is with high probability a path containing $\alpha n$ vertices, where $\alpha>0$ depends on $c$ (Ajtai-Komlós-Szemerédi 's 1981 paper "The Longest Path in a Random Graph")
- [Alan Frieze](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Texfiles/LongCycles.pdf) sharpened this result, showing that there is with high probability  a cycle containing all but $(1+o_c(1))ce^{-c} n$ vertices, 
  where the $o_c(1)$ notation here means that as $c$ tends to infinity that term tends to $0$.  For large $c$ this is essentially tight -- the graph contains roughly $ce^{-c} n$ vertices of degree $1$, and your path can't contain more than $2$ of them.  This result was later extended to directed graphs by [Krivelevich, Lubetsky, and Sudakov](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.3147.pdf).
- If $p=\frac{\ln n + \ln \ln n + \omega(1)}{n}$, where $\omega(1)$ is any function tending to infinity with $n$, then the graph almost surely has a Hamiltonian cycle (see linked paper in mr. gondolier's comment for a stronger result along these lines)

Comment: I think you meant \omega(1). BTW, this is due to Komlos and Szemeredi http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X83900213

Comment: Indeed.  Thank you for the correction/link!